# Sorting columns in a sparse matrix with specific order R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix m where the rows are genes and the columns are barcodes,that I want to sort the columns in a specific order.

```
> m = matrix(c(2,3,3,1,0,7), nrow=2, ncol=3)
> dimnames(m) = list(c("gene1", "gene2"), c("A-1", "B-1", "C-2"))
> m
      A-1 B-1 C-2
gene1   2   3   0
gene2   3   1   7
>
```

I have another data frame where the first column contains the all the barcodes in sorted order.

```
> colnames(df) <- c('Barcode', "Cluster")
> df
  Barcode Cluster
1     B-1       9
2     C-2       1
3     A-1       14
>
```

How do I sort the sparse matrix m so that I get this?

```
> m
      B-1 C-2 A-1
gene1   3   0   2
gene2   1   7   3
```

Comment: Extract the column 'Barcode' and use that as column index assuming it is character class  `m[, df$Barcode]`.  If it is `factor`, convert to `character` `m[, as.character(df$Barcode)]`

Comment: That worked thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming df$Barcode is 'character' class you can do the following:

m <- m[,df$Barcode]

E.g. this works for your example:

m <- m[,c("B-1","C-2","A-1")]

```
> m
      B-1 C-2 A-1
gene1   3   0   2
gene2   1   7   3
```